# Firefox not hiding cursor using cursor: none;

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I've made a simple demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/bwmgazfx/1/

The line of CSS works in Chrome and IE11.

```
*, html { cursor: none !important; }
```

In Chrome and IE11 the cursor is hidden, but in Firefox (version 60)the cursor sometimes hides when you hold the mouse button down but otherwise stays visible. I know that cursor: none; works in Firefox but I can't seem to track down the problem as to why it's not being hidden.

My question is, why is the cursor not hidden in Firefox 61?

Comment: why not just change the cursor to an image of the red dot? then you wouldn't need all the js too

Comment: I think that as something to do with iframes: you can't hide the cursor with `cursor: none` on iframes I believe.

Comment: it seem to be working at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=none so i believe this is a problem with jsfiddle. have you tried jsut creating a local .html file on your computer to test it?

Comment: if you change it to cursor:help or something on js fiddle, you can see that the help icon blinks trough once in a while, so it is probably just an iframe issue like Ivan suggests

Comment: (What are you actually trying to achieve here? Depending on what browser support you need, `cursor: url()` might be a simpler way to achieve the desired effect perhaps … without the need for _any_ JavaScript in that regard.)

Comment: No, it has todo with an issue some browsers keep showing the cursor if the document height is not filled 100%

Comment: Yeah I think it's stupid too, but they want a 'ripple' effect on click and some other things, which was easier to get done with a bit of JavaScript. I prefer the normal cursor :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your CSS is correct, however, some browsers (your case FireFox) will still show the cursor if the document height is not filled 100%

Adding below to your CSS will fix this.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

```js
var x = null;
var y = null;

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseUpdate, false);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseUpdate, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onClickMouse, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onReleaseMouse, false);

var $mousePointer = document.getElementById('mouse-pointer');

function onMouseUpdate(e) {
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
    
    $mousePointer.style.top = y + "px";
    $mousePointer.style.left = x + "px";
}

function onClickMouse(e) {
    $mousePointer.style.transform = "matrix(0.75, 0, 0, 0.75, 0, 0)";
}

function onReleaseMouse(e) {
    $mousePointer.style.transform = "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)";
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

*, html {
  cursor: none;
}

body {
    background-image: url(tile.jpg); 
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#mouse-pointer { 
    width: 12px; 
    height: 12px; 
    position: absolute; 
    background-color: red; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    transition: transform 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouse-pointer"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting, any source / bug-report as to why they do that?

Comment: Thanks, when I added it to the full page it worked fine so I couldn't work out why my demo version wouldn't work.

Comment: @Kaiido Not that I'm aware off, I found this out a long time ago. A guy pointed that out. Don't remember the source.

Comment: @Red fair enough. If you ever find it back, be kind to remind me. (Did a quick search on ff bugzilla with no result...)

Comment: @Kaiido Sure, will do.