# JS / CSS: Overwrite MAGNIFIED-macOS-CURSOR, inside of website

Tags: javascript, css, macos

I just created a custom cursor, by chaining a div to the mouse-position and setting the cursor to: `cursor: none;`

*( I have a fiddle right here: https://jsfiddle.net/pv0647dn/ )*

**The Problem:**
On macOS, when you move your cursor really fast, the cursor changes to a bigger version of itself. So when you're on a website, with the custom cursor from the fiddle, and you move your mouse really fast, the second, larger, cursor, that's part of the OS, appears. – I would like for this cursor to not appear, or to change it. (Inside of a website.)

If I had to guess, I'd say this is not possible, but maybe it is… Any ideas?

Comment: Just to let you know, on Firefox Win10, the regular cursor is still appearing in you JSFiddle. See here for why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874665/firefox-not-hiding-cursor-using-cursor-none/50875191

Comment: You need a defined height for some reason. Really weird. I added a link to my initial comment that explains it.

Comment: @AndyMercer Oh, I saw the edit, though I didn't read it the first time, and deleted my comment. Haha. – Thank You!