# cursor not hidden after applying cursor:none; only in firefox using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api, web-deployment

In only fire fox the cursor is not hidden when I change the cursor style "pointer" to "none" using java script over you tube Embeded video. I am using a extra div over Iframe to trigger the event to to hide the cursor. When I am inspect the element I see cursor property is none, but in just display its not hidden but work fine in chrome, edge.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: If this is only for the firefox browser then you can clear the cache of your browser, stop the project and run again your project. It may solve the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yeah after clearing cache its not working

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the document's height not being filled to 100%. As ridiculous as it may seem, some versions of Firefox require this to display certain CSS attributes properly.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874665/firefox-not-hiding-cursor-using-cursor-none) thread for specifics. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: it is in full screen mode, but the div taking full screen height and width.

Comment: i want to hide cursor and custom control bar when mouse is not moving, over the you tube embeded video while full screen mode in my webpage